# How to create phonegap blackberry application in eclipse?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

i have download and installed the blackberry java plug-in 2.0.0 fine.Eclipse opened successfully, but when i am going to create new blackberry project, it is giving only three options such as, Blackberry project,Blackberry Resource File,Blackberry Screen.Now i want to create blackberry web work project for phonegap application.How to make this kind of project i mean how to make phonegap project in blackberry eclipse.what i want to do next?Now i can create sample native blackberry apps, but i want to make a phonegap blackberry application.That is why i am asking.please reply me with corresponding result...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current eclipse plugin that I know of for creating a BBOS phonegap project. What you can do is grab the latest version of Phonegap that had BBOS in it (2.9) from here - http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/ and follow the instructions here http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_blackberry_index.md.html#BlackBerry%20Platform%20Guide